# iPhone writeToFile doesn't work

Tags: iphone

I have written one application that save txt file into device. When I test on simulator, I am able to read and write file. After I test on device, read is working fine but it doesn't write anything on that text file. I have searched for the solution but it seems like it has problem with right access. Anyone can suggest me how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

What path are you using to save the file to?

I'm using

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFileNameHere.txt"];

}
```

and then pass `[self dataFilePath];` into the writeToFile method as the path

Answer (score 2):

On real device you don't have access to write everywhere. See ["Commonly Used Directories"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW12) in Developers Guide - you should write to Documents or Caches directories ([how to get their paths](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW6))